# Random Batch update returned unexpected row count from update: 0 actual row count: 0 expected: 1

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldbox

I've been trying to resolve this error for many days now, and I'm not getting anywhere fast. I've found many other articles discussing this particular error, but I believe my situation is a bit unique.

I'm getting the error below in a production environment. I have not been able to replicate in development or staging environment. It is completely random. Sometimes it may happen back to back and other times, it will happen couple of times every hour.

> Either the updated/deleted row does not exist or the session contained
>   stale data. Root cause :org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch
>   update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row
>   count: 0; expected: 1

I have a very simple User CFC ORM and at the time the user logs in, I update the last login date. That's it, but it randomly throws an error. I have enabled SQL logging, but I don't see anything suspicious. In the log, I see my update statement running with all the applicable parameter values.

The user table has some triggers that do update the table; however, I have disabled all applicable triggers, but I still randomly get the error.

Lastly, I'm not doing anything weird with the primary key as you can see from the code below.

```
component
    persistent="true"
    table="Users"
    schema="dbo"
{
    // id
    property name="id" column="usersID" fieldtype="id" ormtype="int" type="numeric" generator="native";

    // fields
    property name="type" column="userType" ormtype="short" type="numeric";
    property name="loginType" ormtype="short" type="numeric";
    property name="fname" ormtype="string" type="string";
    property name="middle" ormtype="string" type="string";
    property name="lname" ormtype="string" type="string";
    property name="username" ormtype="string" type="string";
    property name="phone" ormtype="string" type="string";
    property name="email" ormtype="string" type="string";
    property name="userDSN" ormtype="string" type="string";
    property name="enPassword" ormtype="string" type="string";
    property name="range" ormtype="string" type="string";
    property name="isPasswordExpired" column="changePassword" ormtype="short" type="numeric" default="0";
    property name="lastPasswordChangeDate" column="lastPasswordChange" ormtype="timestamp" type="date";
    property name="isLocked" ormtype="boolean" type="boolean";
    property name="lockedDate" ormtype="timestamp" type="date";
    property name="invalidLoginCount" ormtype="short" type="numeric" default="0";
    property name="lastLogin" ormtype="timestamp" type="date";
    property name="isActive" column="active" ormtype="boolean" type="boolean";

    // Non-Persistable Fields
    property name="password" persistent="false" type="string" default="";
    property name="loggedIn" persistent="false" type="boolean" default="false";

    public User function init() {
        setLoggedIn(false);

        return this;
    }

    public string function getFullName() {
        return getFname() & (len(trim(getMiddle())) ? " " & getMiddle() : "" ) & " " & getLname();
    }

    public boolean function isLoggedIn() {
        return getLoggedIn();
    }

    public void function resetLockout() {
        setIsLocked(0);
        setLockedDate(javaCast("null", ""));
        setInvalidLoginCount(0);
    }
}
```

This application is using CF 11 with Coldbox, and MSSQL 2008.

Anyway, any help I can get on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is the entity stored in session scope or anything like that? Do you have any other processes that update the data (I know you mentioned triggers but you may have scheduled tasks or other apps that access the same database). Have you checked that the data exists in the table?

Comment: @JohnWhish The entity is not stored in the session. There are two other apps that use the same database and table, but they would not touch the same user record at the same time. I have checked and the data does exist. As I mentioned, the error occurs right after authenticating the user and try to update the last login date/time on the user record. Users table is a busy table for sure, but I can't imagine two separate process trying to update the same record simultaneously. Would a cflock or a transaction block help in any way?

Comment: Hibernate loads the entity once per request and then does the updates at the end of the request (depending on your ormsettings), so if you had a long running request it could change although unlikely. You could try forcing ORM to save when you tell it to by calling `ORMFlush()` after it (although that's a heavy handed approach but worth a try even if it just proves that this is what is happening). Ideally you should be using transactions where you can.